# Oneplus One is not recognised at all by Windows 10

Tags: cyanogenmod, windows, usb-drivers, oneplus-one

I've been having this problem for a long time, can't remember how much exactly. No matter what I've tried, I haven't managed to get my computer recognize my opo **(Cyanogen 13.0)**.

When I connect it absolutely nothing happens. The device manager doesn't flash (doesn't recognize a new device connected), so I cannot find/update/remove the drivers anyhow.

*Developer options* on my phone have a bunch of things but none seems relevant, apart from open/close Android debugging (adb) and select *USB Configuration* (Charging/MTP/PTP etc). I've tried several options, nothing seems to change.

I've also installed some Windows MTP drivers (see [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/mtp-windows-10-helpful-stuff.418365/)) which were supposedly solving the issue caused by a Windows 10 update, but no luck (which could have been the issue, but can't be sure-I can't remember the last time I was able to browse my phone's memory).

Any ideas? It seems so strange to me that I am the only one with that issue. 
I know CM was abandoned and was thinking to change to another version, but I can't even move my files right now :(

Comment: Does this happen on Windows 10 only ? Did you try on another computer/Windows version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it might sound dumb, but it was the cables' fault after all.

I had already tried two different (one of them was the original which worked fine until some time ago), but none of them worked so I figured something else was wrong. Until I came across a third one, which seems to be the only functional one....

Thanks anyway! and beware of your cables xD

Answer (score 0):

When the mobile phone is connected to the computer, mobile phone down the status bar, click is connected to the USB debugging, and then click on the file transfer, I hope you can understand, because these words from Baidu Translate, I am a Chinese developer

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to use third-party Oppo PC suite: Mobogenie, Moborobo, MOBILedit and others; try to Google it and you will find the links to download the software. These utilities can help you to connect your Oppo device to computer.

Answer (score 0):

usb wire is the only problem...a normal usb cables has 4 small wires in it for audio video or any file transfer and charging your device....so of what i could think of in this case there could be 2 problems in your usb cable :-

1. some usb cables are only made for charging your device and hence only have two wires inside them and so there are no wires for transfer of files and hence not recognised by device or computer

2.this one could be rare but possibly the two wires responsible for the transfer of files are some broken somewhere in between and hence behave as a wire which is only used for charging and hence ur device and computer cannot recognize it.

so the only solution is to try changing the usb cable..and it should work

thank you